# Create a DataFrame with a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I would like to make my DataFrame like the one below and export it to excel. I have all the data available for all the '-' that I have put. I want to know what data structure to pass to pd.Dataframe() to make a table like this.

Would like to know how pandas read these data structures to form a DataFrame.

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Zara', 'LV', 'Roots'],
                                  ['Orders', 'GMV', 'AOV']],
                                 names=['Brand', 'Metric'])
col = ['Yesterday', 'Yesterday-1', 'Yesterday-7', 'Thirty day average']

df = pd.DataFrame('-', idx, col)
df
```

***Jupyter screen shot***

[image]

```
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

***Mac Numbers screen shot***

[image]