when indexed all values loaded into a pandas DataFrame becoming nan values
Hello I'm fairly new to Python, I'm using this code to enter this DataSet into a pandas dataset with hierarchical indexing
,,,# Task 2
# Merge datasets
data2 = pd.read_csv('OneDrive/a. Masters Degree/Module 8 Advanced Programming/week 5/CollegeGrades2.csv')
display('\nDataset1:\n',data)

frame3 = pd.DataFrame(data1a, index = [['Year 1','Year 1', 'Year 2', 'Year 2', 'Evening', 'Evening'],
                                       ['M','F','M','F','M','F']],
                      columns = [['Whitby','Whitby','Whitby','Whitby','Whitby','Whitby','Whitby','Whitby','Whitby','Whitby','Whitby','Whitby','Bridlington','Bridlington','Bridlington','Bridlington','Bridlington','Bridlington','Bridlington','Bridlington','Bridlington','Bridlington','Bridlington','Bridlington'],
                                 ['Art','Art','Art','Art', 'Engineering','Engineering','Engineering','Engineering', 'Psychology', 'Psychology', 'Psychology', 'Psychology','Mathematics','Mathematics','Mathematics','Mathematics', 'Chemistry', 'Chemistry', 'Chemistry', 'Chemistry', 'Technology', 'Technology', 'Technology', 'Technology'],
                                 ['F','P','M','D','F','P','M','D','F','P','M','D','F','P','M','D','F','P','M','D','F','P','M','D']]),,,

when this code is run in python all the values turn to NaN values in the new DataFrame, when I need something more like bellow:




Unnamed: 0
Unnamed: 1
Whitby
Unnamed: 3
Unnamed: 4
Unnamed: 5
Unnamed: 6
Unnamed: 7
Unnamed: 8
Unnamed: 9
...
Unnamed: 28
Unnamed: 29
Unnamed: 30
Unnamed: 31
Unnamed: 32
Unnamed: 33
Unnamed: 34
Unnamed: 35
Unnamed: 36
Unnamed: 37




1
NaN
NaN
Art
NaN
NaN
NaN
Engineering
NaN
NaN
NaN
...
NaN
NaN
Chemistry
NaN
NaN
NaN
Technology
NaN
NaN
NaN


3
NaN
NaN
F
P
M
D
F
P
M
D
...
M
D
F
P
M
D
F
P
M
D


5
Year 1
M
0
5
7
9
2
18
5
10
...
6
2
0
10
11
14
4
12
12
5


7
NaN
F
0
13
14
11
0
6
8
6
...
14
9
10
11
18
20
0
5
7
8


9
Year 2
M
5
10
6
6
1
20
5
18
...
6
2
1
13
15
18
3
19
8
16


11
NaN
F
1
11
14
15
0
9
9
2
...
14
9
0
17
19
19
0
4
6
4


13
Evening
M
4
10
6
5
3
13
19
5
...
6
2
8
12
16
13
4
19
18
7


15
NaN
F
4
12
12
13
0
9
3
8
...
14
9
9
16
20
13
0
10
5
6



[8 rows x 38 columns]

Where did data1a come from and what does it contain?

That was a typo, should be data2

data2 is already a dataframe (pd.read_csv reads data from a CSV source into a dataframe). If you only want to alter columns and indexes, there are other ways to do it. Adding the current dataframe (data2) structure would be more helpful to your question.

Looks like you need MultiIndex : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901145/create-a-dataframe-with-a-multiindex
